# Naming convention in Redux - Is 'reducer' the whole file or just one function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, naming-conventions

I have small question about naming convention in Redux:

Is `reducer` the whole file: `auth.reducer.js`

or it is just one of many "functions" (cases) inside file:

```
...
  case LOGOUT_USER:
    return {
    ...state,
    loading: true,
  };
...
```

so then file needs to be named `auth.reducers.js`

When we speak about `actions`, `types`, `sagas` there are many of them inside file so file should be named in plural.

Answer (score 2):

**!!! Multiple reducer function in the same reducer.js file is also possible.**

As mentioned by `Dan Abramov`(author of redux) in this tutorial 
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-implementing-combinereducers-from-scratch

it is still possbile to implement multiple reducer function in the same reducer file. If you decide to implement different reducer functions in the same reducer file, you should apply `combineReducer(reducer1, reducer2)` and finally export this combined reducer.

For example:

```
const todosReducer = combineReducers({todoReducer, visibilityReducer});

export default todosReducer;
```

This design pattern help us to split the reducer logic in different reducers, and make the code more readable and testable.

Comment: Yes. In that case xxx.reducers.js will be the proper naming rather than xxx.reducer.js.

Answer (score 0):

> Is reducer the whole file: auth.reducer.js

Yes, it is.

According to MDN:

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on
>   each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

Every reducer file contains a single method, not methods, which has different cases. And, that returns a single output - state, not a combination of or different outputs.
Every `reducer` results in a single state object, which is later combined through `combineReducers`.

We are expecting the same from `auth.reducer.js`.

Comment: The MDN citation in this answer is for [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which has absolutely nothing to do with redux.